# select * vs select column in Redshift and MySql

Tags: mysql, performance, bigdata, amazon-redshift, rdbms

If I just need 2/3 columns and I query `SELECT *` instead of providing those columns in select query, is there any performance degradation regarding more/less I/O or memory in Redshift and MySql?

Basically I want to understand comparison `select *` and `select column` in Redshift and MySql in which database which query is faster and why ??

Comment: There are a lot of questions here (I/O, memory, speed). Have you tried or profiled anything yourself? You definitely have a valid hunch, though, because RedShift storage is generally columnar. In fact, the [RedShift docs](https://aws.amazon.com/redshift/pricing/) say this: "You can improve query performance and reduce costs by storing data in a compressed, partitioned, columnar data format...if you store data in a columnar format, such as Parquet or ORC, your charges will also go down as Redshift Spectrum scans only the columns needed by the query."

Comment: I would expect both to have the same execution plan, so on the DB itself the performance should be fairly similar.  On the other hand, if `select *` would result in much more data being sent than selecting on only a few columns, then the former would perform less from a network bandwidth point of view.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen@RayToal thanks for your reply, I know that SELECT * is always costly because it take more I/O, memory, process more data etc. but basically I want to understand query execution in difference in Column database and Row database.

Comment: You might be missing the point of my comment.  I am trying to tell you that the execution strategies of both queries is probably the same.  But, if you want more columns, then there could definitely be a performance difference, especially if the extra columns are particularly large.

Comment: ALWAYS select only the columns you actually want returned- even if that's all of them. Do t use evil SELECT *.

Answer (score 2):

As RedShift is Columnar database,

> Select Column1,Clumn2 from table_a where some_criteria

The particular column select queries will be ***super fast*** because Redshift needs to just scan/read the particular column only.

While Select * will be much slower as Redshift need to scan and read all the columns.

In case of MySql as well, select col1,col2 from table_a will be OK(as less memory/IO), but, not as good as Redshift.

I would recommend you to read some really good documentation about columnar database like Redshift, its distribution key concept and encoding concept while also impacts performance greatly.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iuQgZDs-W7A

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL, there may be a small or large difference:

- Large:  If `*` has `TEXT` or `BLOB` columns that are not present in the 2/3.  This is because, in some cases, such fields require an extra disk hit to fetch.
- Small otherwise.  (More to parse, more to allocate memory for, etc.)